# Box API 2.0 Set shared_link returns 404

Tags: box-api

Recently I have been playing with Box.com's API version 2.0.

According to the official description in 
[this document](http://developers.box.com/docs/#files-create-a-shared-link-for-a-file), I can set "access" to "Open" for a file successfully.

However, if I change it to either "company" or "collaborators", the server returns a response saying HTTP 404 not found as the following shows.

```
{
   "type":"error",
   "status":404,
   "code":"not_found",
   "help_url":"http:\/\/developers.box.com\/docs\/#errors",
   "message":"Not Found",
   "request_id":"609097837503b1dabc4d0c"
}
```

And I cannot figure out what exactly does "not found" means by this message.

This is the request body I sent that is OK

```
{
   "shared_link":{
      "access":"Open",
      "permissions":{
         "download":true,
         "preview":true
      }
   }
}
```

This is the request body that returns me error

```
{
   "shared_link":{
      "access":"company",
      "permissions":{
         "download":true,
         "preview":true
      }
   }
}
```

I am wondering whether its something I should not do or it is just a bug in the api.

Thanks in advance for any response.

================================

Some update to the question.

I am afraid it is not a case related problem 
though the example on the document when I saw them do use uppercase "Open".

In my situation, either using "Open" or "open", 
I can successfully set the sharelink without any problem.

However, the behavior of following cases is a little bit odd to me.

**case 1: Setting both properties( download and preview) in permissions to false** returns 404
(setting only one of them to true works properly)

```
{
   "shared_link":{
      "access":"Open",
      "permissions":{
         "download":false,
         "preview":false
      }
   }
}
```

In following cases, for illustrating purpose I first set "access" as "Open".

**case 2: Setting "access" to "Collaborators"** returns 404 not found

**case 3: Setting "access" to "collaborators"**
Works ok, but the json response did not correctly shows the "access" as "collaborators"

Following is the excerpt from the response of case 3, "access" is still "Open"

```
    shared_link": {
    "url": "https://www.box.com/s/03a47eb4b7dce0439d7f",
    "download_url": "https://www.box.com/shared/static/03a47eb4b7dce0439d7f.pdf",
    "password_enabled": false,
    "unshared_at": null,
    "download_count": 0,
    "preview_count": 0,
    "access": "Open",
    "permissions": {
        "download": true,
        "preview": true
    }
```

"Company" seems the same with previous cases so I stop here.

And out of curiosity I set the "access" to arbitrary characters other than those mentioned on the document(I tried words like "pp", "c", "test"), 
interestingly the server seems all returns 200:OK but the json response remains "access":"Open". Rather confusing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out that the "access" parameter was case-sensitive.   We've now fixed that, so that "Open" and "open" etc both work.

It turns out that you are also exposing a couple of tricky edge cases around file-sharing.  There are some security settings that you can set, such as the "Folder Properties: Security" setting that says "Restrict shared links to collaborators only."

[image]

It turns out that if you have set this setting, that API calls to set the "access" to "open", we'll return a 404.   We'll work on making that a more informative error (like a 403, access denied).

As for the rest of the cases.

**case 1:** Our web-ui restricts you from setting some of those combinations (like download=false and preview=false) because when we built the sharing features, we didn't think it would make sense to have a non-downloadable, non-previewable file.

**case 2 (and part of case 3):** setting to "Collaborators" or "collaborators" should work fine now.  Bug was fixed.

**case 3:** setting to "co" or "foo" was defaulting to "Open."  We've now changed that to return an error (404 again).

Hope that helps.

Comment: I am afraid it's not a case-related problem.  I updated my question for more illustration.